# query order by 2nd column when score is equal

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using this formula to order column G to sort the highest points of the player list.

```
=QUERY(A2:G;"select * where A is not null order by G desc";0)
```

Some of the players have equal total points, but not equal times. Points are earned over different rounds, based on what time they finished.

If the players have equal points, I want to sort by a second column (their total finishing time) in column H.

example:
Both players finished 1st & 2nd. The total time has a difference of 1 minute. Player 2 should be ordered first based on his total time.
Note that I can't directly order by "Total Time" due to the point system in the background.

```
Player   Round1   Round2   Points   Total Time
  1       3min     1min      10        4min
  2       1min     2min      10        3min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
=QUERY(A2:G;"select * where A is not null order by G desc, H asc";0)
```